# Go back to start at the end of a scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I created a kind of fake scroll using JS as my boss is using a Mac and scrollbars are turned off by default and he wanted to see what was going on.

My code for this is like so:

```js
$(function() {
 var popular_products_span = $("#popular_products_span");
 var items = popular_products_span.children();
 popular_products_span.prepend('<div id="right-button"><a href="#"><</a></div>');
 popular_products_span.append('<div id="left-button"><a href="#">></a></div>');
 items.wrapAll('<div id="inner" />');
 popular_products_span.find('#inner').wrap('<div id="outer"/>');
 var outer = $('#outer');
 var updateUI = function() {
  var maxWidth = outer.outerWidth(true);
  var actualWidth = 0;
  $.each($('#inner >'), function(i, item) {
   actualWidth += $(item).outerWidth(true);
  });
 };
 updateUI();
 $('#right-button').click(function() {
  var leftPos = outer.scrollLeft();
  outer.animate({
   scrollLeft: leftPos - 300
  }, 300);
 });
 $('#left-button').click(function() {
  var leftPos = outer.scrollLeft();
  outer.animate({
   scrollLeft: leftPos + 300
  }, 300);
 });
 $(window).resize(function() {
  updateUI();
 });
});
```

```css
#popular_products_span{
 overflow:hidden;
}
img{
 padding:10px;
}
#outer {
 float:left;
 width:400px;
 overflow:hidden;
 white-space:nowrap;
 display:inline-block;
}
#left-button {
 float:left;
}
#right-button {
 float:left;
}
#inner:first-child {
 margin-left:0;
}
.hide {
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="popular_products_span">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
</span>
```

However, I want it to scroll through endlessly so instead of coming to an end you will go back to the start again and am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: So you want to wrap around?

Comment: Yeah I'd like to make it continuous

Comment: Do you want it to look endless in general or do you want it to snap back to the beginning and begin again?

Comment: Why don't use an existing carousel such as [owlcarousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html)

Comment: I'd like it to look endless but either way would work

Comment: owlcarousel support it. See the demo..

Comment: @MoshFeu Thanks for your suggestion I've had a look at it but would rather try figure out a way to do it myself. +1 anyway though for the suggestion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using much easier
https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/